# Strategy for mapping entity relationships and converting entities

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, ejb, crud

I am just learning java ee 6. My goal is having a simple crud application which let me create edit list and delete one trivial entity made simply by the id, a name string and a description string. I followed this just to see some  code http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html I used eclipse instead of netbeans and jboss 7 instead of glass fish. Well.... It works.

Now think my entity is a "User": id, username, Password.
I want to add a "UserRole" entity and here it is: id, rolename.
Then I set a OneToMany and a ManyToOne relationship.

So, how can I manage the role input in the create user page?
Netbeans crud suggested code is a selectonemenu (a select drop down list) with all the roles ids as values. On form submit a static inner class "roleconverter" (a facesconverter) in the role controller (the jsf managed bean) takes the selected and submitted role Id string and looks up for the corresponding role using a ejb-dao.

My questions are:

- do I understand? Is what I wrote above correct?
- is using a converter in that way the best best practice? Doesn't a better solution exist for such a simple and recurrent task?
- converters for entities are all the same except for the entity name, how can I remove the duplication, for example with a generic converter?
- what's the best GUI in your opinion for managing many to many in jsf 2? (e.g. A user with multiple roles scenario)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. The converter is required because HTML is basically one big `String` and HTTP request parameters are all `String`s. HTML and HTTP doesn't understand nor pass around concrete Java objects. They live in webserver's memory only. You'd really need to be able to convert between `SomeRandomEntity` and `String` in order to generate HTML response and parse HTTP request parameters properly.

As to the converters being not really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), if all your entities extend a common base entity wherein the `@Id` is definied along with the getter and setter, and you've a generic DAO, then you could create a generic converter for this. Something like this (trivial prechecking and `ConverterException` handling omitted):

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Long id = ((BaseEntity) value).getId();
    return String.valueOf(id);
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Long id = Long.valueOf(value);
    Class<BaseEntity> type = (Class<BaseEntity>) component.getValueExpression("value").getType(context.getELContext());
    return genericDAO.find(id, type);
}
```

Alternatively, in the particular case of `<h:selectOneMenu>`, you could also use a converter which converts based on the object values of `<f:selectItem(s)>`. This is however not exactly trivial. The JSF2 component library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has such a [`SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) in its assortiment. You may want to check its source code if interested.