# jsf2 converter usage for update model or render

Tags: jsf-2

I am new bee to jsf    , I am using prime faces, I did not understand   how converter works, in case of single select menu.
My confusion is, is it called for converting   from request parameter to  object in formBean  or is it called for rendering my list?
In my list If I specify

```
<f:selectItems
                                value="#{granteeSelectionManager.getGrantProgramDTOs()}"
                                var="grantProgramDTO" itemLabel="#{grantProgramDTO.name}"
                                itemValue="#{grantProgramDTO.id}" />
```

how to render my list   and specify a converter, the  converter is beign called for every item in the list?

Please help me understand if it is called for updating selection in my managed bean or for rendering or both ?

Answer (score 0):

It's used for both cases.

When the list is rendered, the converter's `getAsString()` is used to convert the Java object behind `<f:selectItem(s) itemValue>` to a `String` which in turn is rendered as `<option value>` (which in turn is used as HTTP request parameter). This is indeed done on a per-item basis.

When the form is submitted, the converter's `getAsObject()` is used to convert the submitted value (the `<option value>` which appears as HTTP request parameter) back to the concrete Java object so that it can be set in the model (the backing bean) via `<x:selectOneMenu value>`.

---

In *your particular case* you seem to use object's own `id` property as item value. In such case a converter is completely unnecessary. You only need to make sure that `<x:selectOneMenu value>` is bound to a property of exactly the same type as `<f:selectItem(s) itemValue>`, which is probably `Integer` or `Long`.

If you however want to get and set a concrete Java object as value like so

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.grantProgramDTO}">
    <f:selectItems ... itemValue="#{grantProgramDTO}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

then you definitely need a converter for the simple reason that Java objects can't be represented in HTML output and HTTP request parameters without converting them to their unique `String` representation first. In Java perspective, HTML output is basically one large `String` and HTTP request parameters are [per definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) `String`s.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [Why selectOneMenu Send ItemLabel to the converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022965/why-selectonemenu-send-itemlabel-to-the-converter/7031334#7031334)
- [Is a custom JSF converter needed for this simple class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921381/is-a-custom-jsf-converter-needed-for-this-simple-class/1921443#1921443)
- [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734580/jsf-2-selection-combo-box-with-without-conversion-strategy/4735322#4735322)
- [Strategy for mapping entity relationships and converting entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439732/strategy-for-mapping-entity-relationships-and-converting-entities/10439875#10439875)
- [How create a custom coverter in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001079/how-create-a-custom-coverter-in-jsf-2/8001418#8001418)